# The differential of Gauss' map is zero if and only if $S$ is a plane

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold

Assume that the second fundamental form of a surface $S$ is identically equal to zero. It is well-known (and easy to be shown) that the surface is part of a plane!
However, let me think geometrically to this situation. The Gauss' map $N$ is constant in this case, so that the span of $\sigma_u$ and $\sigma_v$ (here $\sigma$ denotes the parameterization of $S$) is always the same vector space. Now, from that, can I deduce that $\sigma_u$ and $\sigma_v$ are constant vectors?

Comment: A plane also admits parameterizations where $\sigma_u$ and $\sigma_v$ are not constant.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Please edit the question: "so that the span of $\sigma_u$ and $\sigma_v$ ..."?

Comment: Try parametrizing the plane in polar coordinates.

Comment: $(u,v)\mapsto (\mathrm{argth} u, \mathrm{argth} v,0)$ is a local parametrization of the plane $\{z=0\}$ that has non constant $\sigma_u$ and $\sigma_v$.

Comment: @Didier Perhaps I'm the only one who does not know what argth stands for ... I guess $\sinh u$ would suffice.

Comment: @TedShifrin That was the first thing that came up in my mind sorry !

Comment: @Didier Any diffeomorphism of the plane onto iself works, right?

Comment: @TheWanderer exactly.